# Gerber file mirrored

Tags: pcb, gerber

it's the first time that I create gerber files for a pcb printing website. I'm looking to the bottom layer with a gerber view, but it doesn't seem to be mirrored...
[image]

it's the same view as in eagle, i.e. from the top. Is this ok or not?

thanks

Comment: Yeah, that's fine mate. My gerbers show the same way (bottom layer is viewed as if through the top, not from the bottom). The PCB manufacturer will take that and flip it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - it should be possible to view all the Gerbers in the stackup at once and have them line up. The PCB house will flip them according to whether they're "top" or "bottom".

See [After the PCB is designed, what do I need to check in the Gerber files?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7820/after-the-pcb-is-designed-what-do-i-need-to-check-in-the-gerber-files?rq=1)